# How can I use a PowerShell output in the next command?

Tags: powershell

I am working on a PowerShell command to search across drives for a specific file. I am new to PowerShell so most of what I have already is just stuff I found online. At the moment I have this:

```
$ExclDrives = ('C')
>> Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object {$_.Name -notin $ExclDrives} `
>> | % {write-host -f Green "Searching " $_.Root;get-childitem $_.Root -include *MyFile.txt -r `
>> | sort-object Length -descending}
```

Which outputs this:

```
Searching  D:\
Searching  E:\
Searching  F:\


    Directory: F:\MyDirectory


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         8/13/2022  12:03 AM              0 MyFile.txt


PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

I would like to know how I can take the directory that is listed in the output and use it in a following command such as:

```
cd F:\MyDirectory
```

If this is possible through piping or something I would really appreciate an answer :)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't really sure what the best way to handle this would be if multiple files were found.  We wouldn't be able to change directory into the parent folders while the script was running nor would we be able to do so for all of the returned files unless we opened new PowerShell windows for each.  Since it appears that you will be searching for specific files which I assume will not return too many results and not knowing your ultimate goal I went with opening a new file explorer window for each file with the file being highlighted/selected.

```
$excludeDrives = ('C')
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object { $_.Name -notin $excludeDrives } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host -f Green 'Searching ' $_.Root
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -Include *MyFile.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach-Object {
                # This line will open a file explorer window with the file highlighted
                explorer.exe /select, $_
                # This line will send the file object out through the pipeline
                $_ 
            } | Sort-Object Length -Descending
        }
```

---

To answer your question about how to access the file's directory in the next command, you can use `Foreach-Object` and `$_.Directory`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -Include *MyFile.txt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Sort-Object Length -Descending |
        ForEach-Object {
            # Using the pipeline we can pass object along and access them
            # using a special automatic variable called $_
            # a property exists on FileInfo objects called Directory
            'The directory is ' + $_.Directory
        }
```

---

### UPDATE

Hopefully this will answer the question in your comment

```
$ExclDrives = ('C')
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $ExclDrives } |
        ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host -f Green 'Searching ' $_.Root
            Get-ChildItem $_.Root -Include *MyFile.txt -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
                ForEach-Object {
                    # do whatever you want with the file.  Reference using $_
                    Write-Host "Found Filename: $($_.Name)`tDirectory: $($_.Directory)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    explorer.exe /select, $_

                    # output the fileinfo object, in this case 
                    # to the next command in the pipeline which is Sort-Object
                    $_
                } |
                    Sort-Object Length -Descending
                }
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, but I have one more question. How do I combine the ability of my original command to search across all drives (except C) with the ability from your command (the 2nd one you gave me) to use the pipeline to pass the object along?

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please see the update at the end of my answer which hopefully addresses your new question.